# jQuery Mobile pageload code executed on first time only

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, pageload

In jQuery Mobile, I am attempting to run scripts on a page at load time. If certain criteria are NOT met, I redirect to another page.
For example PageA  --> click link to PageB --> perform pageload logic --> Redirect to PageC.
All works well the first time I navigate to the PageB.
If I then return to PageA and repeat the navigation to PageB, the redirect does not occur (the pageload logic is not executed).
If I reload PageA and try again, the redirect does occur.

Seems like some kind of caching issue?? Or perhaps I should be using another type of page load event? How can I ensure the pageload logic is executed everytime the page is hit?

Here is a simplified version of the code. The script is called in the head after jqm and jqm mobile scripts.

```
$(document).bind('pageload', function (evt,data) {

    // I need the url to see if the page needs the logic executed on it
    var page = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(""+ data.url +"");
    if (page == "PageB"){
        logicRequired = "yes";    
    }
    switch (logicRequired)
    {
    //==========================
    case 'yes':

        // AJAX call to determine if redirect is needed
        $.ajax({
        url: "scripts/file.php",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data){
            if(data.status == 'success') {
              // do some stuff


            } else if(data.status == 'error') {
              //redirect to another page
              window.location.replace('redirectPage.html');
            }
        },
        error: function(data){
            //alert("There was an error in the ajax call");
        },
      });
      break;
      }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pageload` only fires once each time an external pseudo-page is brought into the DOM. So if you navigate back to that page the event will not fire again. You can however use the `pagebeforeshow` event which fires on the first visit to a pseudo-page as well as subsequent visits to the pseudo-page.

You may also be able to flag the specific pseudo-pages with the `data-cache="false"` attribute so jQuery Mobile deletes the pseudo-page after a user navigates away from the pseudo-page.

Comment: the pagebeforeshow event does not seem to work either -- same behavior using:  $(document).bind('pagebeforeshow', function () { .... etc

Comment: @byoung Can you setup a demonstration of the problem?

Comment: Looks like I misspoke ... the pagebefore event is working fine. Thanks!!